# why sapply() and tapply() have the same result, but not identical?

Tags: r, sapply, tapply

Here's my code

```
pulse <- round(rnorm(22, 70, 10 / 3)) + rep(c(0, 5), c(10, 12))
group <- rep(c("A", "B"), c(10, 12))

tapply(pulse, group, length)

A  B 
10 12

list<-split(pulse,group)
sapply(list,length)

A  B 
10 12
identical(tapply(pulse, group, length),sapply(list,length))#FALSE
identical(tapply(pulse, group, length),as.table(sapply(list,length)))#FALSE
identical(tapply(pulse, group, length),as.vector(sapply(list,length)))#FALSE
identical(as.table(tapply(pulse, group, length)),as.table(sapply(list,length)))#TRUE
```

These two functions generate same results, but why they are not identical? I used typeof() in R, it seems that both of the results with the type "double".

Why identical(tapply(pulse, group, length),sapply(list,length)) is False? How to adjust my code to make them identical?

Thank you.

Comment: If you check the `dput` of each output, one had the `.Names` attributes, while the other it is `.Dimnames`.  By removing the attributes, it will be identical.. ie. ` identical(as.vector(r1), as.vector(r2))#
[1] TRUE`  where v1, v2 are the output of `tapply` and `sapply`.  Or change the attributes i.e. `attributes(r1) <- attributes(r2); identical(r1, r2)`

Comment: Thank you so much. Turns out these two methods have different classes. It works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we check the `str` of each output

```
str(r1)
# int [1:2(1d)] 10 12
#- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
# ..$ : chr [1:2] "A" "B"
str(r2)
# Named int [1:2] 10 12
# - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "A" "B"
```

the `attributes` are different between them.  One way would to remove the `attributes` of each output, and they will be identical

```
 identical(as.vector(r1), as.vector(r2))
 #[1] TRUE
```

But, `as.vector` also removes the `names`.  If we need to keep the `names` part, make the `attributes` same for the outputs

```
 attributes(r1) <- attributes(r2)
 identical(r1, r2)
 #[1] TRUE
```

where

```
r1 <- tapply(pulse, group, length)
r2 <- sapply(list,length)
```